# Внешний вид Netbeans: визуальное отображение "пути" к месту в коде

Tags: netbeans

Подскажите, как выделенный элемент называется и как его активировать (если он до этого был убран)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется **Breadcrumbs**, чтобы его спрятать или показать, нужно проделать следующее:

```
View -> Show Breadcrumbs
```

Буквально переводится, как "хлебные крошки", видимо, по аналогии с событием из одной очень известной сказки братьев Гримм.

Не знаю, чем еще порадовать...